# Generics with List

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance, wildcard

My question is related to lists combined with generics in Java.

I have something like this

```
class A{
}
class B extends A{
}

List<? extends A> list = new ArrayList<A>();
list.add(new A()); //COMPILE ERROR
list.add(new B()); //COMPILE ERROR
```

I do not understand why there is a compilation error even with the assignment `new ArrayList<A>()`.

Comment: The `list` variable has type `List<? extends A>`. The fact that you assigned it an `ArrayList<A>` is irrelevant. The compiler is looking at this list of unknown type and can't be sure you can add `new A()` or `new B()` to it.

Comment: Please learn about upper, lower bound and wildcards in generic.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html